# DOM loading before deferred dynamic script

Tags: javascript, html

My html page creates a dynamic script, where I want to call a function defined in the script after the page loads.  I am manually setting async=false on the dynamic script, but it still gets loaded after the DOM, which causes an error when I try to call the function that is not yet defined.  Can someone tell me how to force the dynamic script to load before the DOMContentLoaded event.  According to all documentation I can find, all scripts should be loaded before DOMContentLoaded event, unless async=true.  I am seeing this behavior in Firefox and Chrome.  Thank you.

Expected order of alerts:

1. script loaded
2. dom load
3. TestFunction called

Order alerts are actually firing:

1. dom load
2. script loaded
3. TestFunction is never called, because browser tried to call it before "script loaded" happened.

HtmlPage1.html:

> ```
> <!DOCTYPE html>
> <html>
> <head>
>     <meta charset="utf-8" />
>     <title></title>
> </head>
> <body>
>
>     <!--<script defer src="JavaScript.js" onload="alert('script loaded');" type="text/javascript"></script>-->
>
>         <script type="text/javascript">
>             (function (n, t, a, e, co) {
>                 var r = t.createElement("script");
>             // dynamic scripts are async by default.  Must change to ensure script loads before dom loaded.
>             r.async = false;
>             //r.defer = true;
>             r.onload = function () {
>                 alert("script loaded");
>                 };
>             r.src = a;
>             var c = t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
>             c.parentNode.insertBefore(r, c);
>             })(window, document, "JavaScript.js");
>
>
>             // have to delay calling TestFunction until after DOM loaded, because script needs to be loaded first
>             document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
>
>                 alert("dom load");
>             TestFunction();
>
>             });
>     </script>
>
>     <div>Test Html Page</div>
> </body>
> </html>
> ```

JavaScript.js:

```
function TestFunction() {
    alert("TestFunction called");
}
```

Comment: Can you use the `load` event in place of the `DOMContentLoaded` event? Is that a workable alternative?

Comment: @Rounin-StandingwithUkraine - the load event would fire before DOMContentLoaded, and my script might be dependent on other things happening in that phase, so I do not want to rely on the option of just moving the logic to the load event.

Comment: Your script will be loaded with a low priority and the loading will start after DOMContentLoaded, because it's a script you add afterwards, If you want it to be loaded with a high priority it should be part of the initial html, not added with js

Comment: Fair enough, @Eric - it's news to me that the `load` event _can_ even fire before `DOMContentLoaded` since I was under the impression that the latter was one of several pre-requisites for the former.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a script tag to a page with js, it will have a low priority, and will be loaded with a delay compared to other high priority scripts, defer and async won't change anything, the loading process will start after the DOMContentLoaded event, because DOMContentLoaded does not take into account dynamically added scripts, it only tracks the loading of the initial html sent back by the server.

Which means a defer script might be loaded before a non-defer script because of the priority, if the defer script is loaded with high priority and the non-defer script is loaded with low priority.

You will need to listen to the load event on the script tag you added if you want to do that.

```js
(function (n, t, a, e, co) {
    var r = t.createElement("script");
    // define an id
    r.id = 'myScript';
    r.onload = function () {
        alert("script loaded");
    };
    r.src = a;
    var c = t.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
    c.parentNode.insertBefore(r, c);
})(window, document, "JavaScript.js");


// listen to the load event of the actual script tag you added
myScript.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    alert("dom load");
    TestFunction();
});
```

If you don't want to do that, you will have to replace your js with an actual script tag in the html :

```js
<script src="JavaScript.js" onload="alert('script loaded');" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
        alert("dom load");
        TestFunction();
    });
</script>
```

now both scripts will be treated as high priority scripts because they are in the initial dom, and listening to DOMContentLoaded will work

Here is a screenshot of the network tab, with a dynamic script vs a static one :

[image: low/high priority]

Comment: is there any documentation that backs up your claims on priority?  I cannot find anything that says dynamic scripts do not obey normal script loading order.  Also, unfortunately I cannot have an inline script declaration, because the src is dynamic.  Thanks.  https://javascript.info/script-async-defer#dynamic-scripts

Comment: They obey the normal script order, but within a same priority, i'm not sure if it's actually documented, pehaps on browsers documentation

Comment: Anyway i think you cant assume a loading order, you will have to listen for the load event of the script thats the only thing that will always work, i've added `<link rel="preload" href="JavaScript.js" as="script" importance="high">` to the head and it does not work even with high priority and async=false, because DOMContentLoaded will not "wait" for scripts added afterwards